# composer update -vvv is not working

Tags: php, composer-php

I have installed composer globally on ubuntu 14.04.
When I run **composer --version** 
it works with the following output

```
Composer version 1.0-dev (45b1f356c24d87788a339f6a50d6d78bef464c47) 2015-02-27 14:31:27
```

But when I run the following command
**composer update -vvv**

It gives the following error

```
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/enamul/.composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I have no idea, why this is happening. Can anyone help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: @kmlnvm the thing is that I have the composer.json on the directory I am in but it's saying that I don't have json at /home/enamul/.composer/composer.json

Comment: I am in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 24):

Just put an empty JSON object into your global config.

```
echo "{}" > ~/.composer/composer.json
```

> Composer will merge this configuration with your project's composer.json when you run the install and update commands.

From the docs https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home

Comment: Is that the command I need to run because I tried vim ~/.composer/composer.json and I was told that ".composer/composer.json" E212: Can't open file for writing when I tried to save and I also copies and pasted that line into my console and it said no such file or directory so I'm lost

Comment: `composer.json` or `config.json`?

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, you should do on the command line:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject
ls -al
cat composer.json
```

All these commands should show the expected thing. I'd expect the directory listing to show the composer.json file being present and having correct access rights for the user you are running as.

```
composer update
```

I have no idea why composer would ever fail, but from my experience it does a pretty good job doing what its supposed to do. Failure usually is caused by minor oversights of obvious things.