# composer is not updateing dependancy with lumen

Tags: laravel, composer-php, lumen, php-5.6

I am using php 5.6.12 version,
I have to compulsory use this version.

running command : `composer update`

it is showing me like below,

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

It is showing this only this since long time, not updates any dependancy of my packages

my composer.json file package as below,

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^32.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "baopham/dynamodb": "^4.11",
        "laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish": "^2.1",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "3.2.*",
        "php-imap/php-imap": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9"
    },
```

I have run `composer update -vvv` command , it gives me below error,

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file E:\xampp7\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt: valid
Executing command (E:\xampp563\htdocs\delrentals-dashboard-api): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Running 1.7.2 (2018-08-16 16:57:12) with PHP 7.0.27 on Windows NT / 6.1
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2016%2421f5855cc4abf8648b47c77d76fee501bfc9fd4d893d6a602e8c8dbd0c4ea0ff.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018-01%24ebbeedf5cdf822efb5bb90b0b147c964df3e11e74d453bbdb6b04b537c180a7e.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-01.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-04.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018-07%240016a26f1005f0fb0be2f409b3fc05dde3132eb7694bc50e386e2a6be4802ee6.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-07.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-10.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest%242eb9ff7604840d5f7b019a1d5770e987526594ecf1528f5fe6b613654914d5c4.json
```

......

I have create composer.json file with empty object "{}"
in location `C:\Users\hetal.gohel\AppData\Roaming\Composer`

```
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file E:\xampp7\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt: valid
Executing command (E:\xampp563\htdocs\delrentals-dashboard-api): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Running 1.7.2 (2018-08-16 16:57:12) with PHP 7.0.27 on Windows NT / 6.1
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-01.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-04.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018-07%24456764a723221fb097b4ae41ef2ce7d91d1207de7b45ed8301c2e0bf1c55387e.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-07.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-10.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest%245fb6a563ef29d0728dfbcf5cc60a8e56619893d5635943fb610b74eb55281719.json
Writing C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-laravel$lumen.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-laravel$lumen-framework.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-illuminate$auth.json from cache
```

.....

It gives still error

Comment: Try `composer update -vvv` to get verbose mode. So we can know where the process is hanging.

Comment: I have run this command , it gives me error, that I have updated in my question,please look into it

Comment: You need to create a `composer.json` file in `C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json`. Just fill it with an empty json object. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785229/composer-update-vvv-is-not-working#answer-32609416

Comment: ok, let me do that

Comment: I have done that, but given still error, I have update it to my question

Comment: It's not an error. `-vvv` option in `composer` give you verbose info what the `composer` is doing. Just wait for it, as long as the process still running and give the info.

Comment: means you say that run command  "composer update" and wait for some time.right ?

Comment: No. I mean run `composer update -vvv` and wait for some time. With `-vvv` you got the progress info in details for the composer update. Without `-vvv`, it will just give you minimal info and you don't know if the process is got stuck somewhere.

Comment: ok.let me do that

Comment: at last line it is showing me like, Resolving dependencies through SAT     
Looking at all rules.        
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #72)

Comment: your solution worked, I have added packaged one by one, instead of all put at time

Comment: thanks, please add your that suggestion in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let me summarize.

Create a composer.json file in `C:/Users/hetal.gohel/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json`. Just fill it with an empty json object `{}`. And then run `composer update -vvv` to see the update process in detail. Just wait until it's done. If the update process takes too long may be you should add the package dependency one by one.